# How do the computational nodes in Snowflake work?

Tags: out-of-memory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, heap-memory

I have an API job crashing often causing memory issue(Java Heap error) leading to other jobs failing. The warehouse is Snowflake(Standard edition) and we have created 6 warehouses. If I isolate the API job for computation, will it save other jobs from crashing? How does Snowflake computational nodes can be utilised here?

Comment: From your description, this doesn't seem to be related to anything happening on the Snowflake side. If your API job crashes and that causes other API jobs to crash then changing anything to do with Snowflake warehouses is not going to help (unless, for some reason, changing the warehouses stops the first job crashing)

Comment: Thanks, NickW. I will try looking into different options to save other jobs.

Comment: How much memory you have assigned for the JVM and how much data are you retrieving from Snowflake? Is the JVM shared by multiple applications?

Comment: I am not sure how can I assign the memory for the JVM, is there any facility to enable this by the user?

Comment: It would depend on how your JVM is being run. Is it a standalone JVM running on your machine/server? Is it embedded in another product? I would recommend you raise this as new question as experts in JVMs are unlikely to find/see this question